# C# wpf datagrid закрасить ячейку

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, datagrid

Прощу строго не судить с wpf первый раз работаю.
Имеется такая табличка [image: таблица]

где <</>> слева данные полученные из станции, а справа установленные порог значении оператором. Как можно сделать чтобы при повышении значении справа закрасилась ячейка в красный цвет?

Прочитал и попробовал эту статью. Не получается

> Окрасить ячейки datagrid wpf

код xml

```
<DataGrid x:Name="observe" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                      AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding MyData}" MinWidth="800" MinHeight="600" Width="1440" Height="500" Margin="0,0,0,-6" CanUserSortColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False">
                <DataGrid.Columns>

                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding station}">
                        <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                            <TextBlock Text="Станция" TextAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="100"/>
                        </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                    </DataGridTextColumn>

                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding tp1}">
                        <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                            <TextBlock Text="°C в аппаратной 1" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="100"/>
                        </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                    </DataGridTextColumn>

                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding tp2}">
                        <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                            <TextBlock Text="°C в аппаратной 2" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="100"/>
                        </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                    </DataGridTextColumn>

                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding mq1}">
                        <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                            <TextBlock Text="кПа в аппаратной 1" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="100"/>
                        </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                    </DataGridTextColumn>

                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding mq2}">
                        <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                            <TextBlock Text="кПа в аппаратной 2" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="100"/>
                        </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                    </DataGridTextColumn>

                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding dd1}">
                        <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                            <TextBlock Text="ДД в аппаратной" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="100"/>
                        </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                    </DataGridTextColumn>

                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding dv1}">
                        <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                            <TextBlock Text="ДВ в аппаратной" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="100"/>
                        </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                    </DataGridTextColumn>

                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding tp3}">
                        <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                            <TextBlock Text="°C в дизельной 1" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="100"/>
                        </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                    </DataGridTextColumn>

                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding tp4}">
                        <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                            <TextBlock Text="°С в дизельной 2" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="100"/>
                        </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                    </DataGridTextColumn>

                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding mq3}">
                        <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                            <TextBlock Text="кПа в дизельной 1" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="100"/>
                        </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                    </DataGridTextColumn>

                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding mq4}">
                        <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                            <TextBlock Text="кПа в дизельной 2" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="100"/>
                        </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                    </DataGridTextColumn>

                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding dd2}">
                        <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                            <TextBlock Text="ДД в дизельной" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="100"/>
                        </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                    </DataGridTextColumn>

                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding dv2}">
                        <DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                            <TextBlock Text="ДВ в дизельной" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="100"/>
                        </DataGridTextColumn.Header>
                    </DataGridTextColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

код MainWindows.cs

```
List<Author> authors = new List<Author>();
        authors.Add(new Author()
        {
            station = rrs[count],
            tp1 = getTP1 + "/" + temp1[count],
            tp2 = getTP2 + "/" + temp2[count],
            mq1 = getMQ1 + "/" + mq1[count],
            mq2 = getMQ2 + "/" + mq2[count],
            dd1 = getDD1 + "/" + dd1[count],
            dv1 = getDV1 + "/" + dv1[count],
            tp3 = getTP3 + "/" + temp3[count],
            tp4 = getTP4 + "/" + temp4[count],
            mq3 = getMQ3 + "/" + mq3[count],
            mq4 = getMQ4 + "/" + mq4[count],
            dd2 = getDD2 + "/" + dd2[count],
            dv2 = getDV2 + "/" + dv2[count],
        });
        observe.Items.Add(newItem: authors);
```

Comment: `IValueConverter`

Comment: @aepot можете объяснить по подробнее? Как `IValueConverter` применить к моему коду?

Comment: Прибиндить фон ячейки через конвертер к ее значению, в конвертере из данных делать цвет.